# Remove email verification when new user register

Tags: users, user-registration

Please note I'm not posting this question without doing google search, but the problem is every single result I found is either about BuddyPress or WP Multisite, but I have a WP Single installation where I use Easy Digital Download and in terms to purchase anything user must have to register first.

But the problem is their account doesn't get activated after registering if they visit customer dashboard it will show up that "Your account is not verified yet so check your email and verify". This is really frustrating for most of my customers as people are so busy now a days and does not have time for these things. After registration user receives email like this - http://puu.sh/kv9fv/9b63ea34f6.jpg

So what I'm asking here **is there any way bu which I can remove this step so that accounts get activated just after register. No need to to email verification.** That's all I wanna know.

Hope to get a reply soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write your own user registration, write a form that gets user details and use `wp_create_user` to create it.

That said, I think email verification is even more important on eCommerce sites, but if you willing to give up the advantages it gives to you and the users, then why not to bypass the whole user registration thing?

Another option is to use SSO provider like facebook and google to make the user creation process faster (you basically rely on them to supply you the current email address of the user).

Comment: is there no other process? No way to disable the email verification without doing such hassle? I know the benefits of it but I don't need it. Is there no simple way to doing that? Like calling some filter or actions and return `false` ?

Comment: sure, but I think it will require more then returning false to some filter. The thing you should probably define first is what should be the registration process. My own experiance from which the answer is derived is that once you are unhappy with the WP login/registretion  there is more then one aspect you will want to change, in your case why do you need user name at all. You need to define first what you want in a positive way (no registration email at all? different ones, no verification at all, or a later one) and then you might be able to hunt for specific hooks.

Comment: If you use wp_create_user function to create a new user then it compulsory to verify. Because if email id is invalid then the function wp_create_user can not accept invalid email and also can not update invalid email.

Comment: @WisdmLabs, invalid != do not exist. anyway like all answers this one is more a concept idea, not something that has to be copy and pasted

Comment: It's mistake by me if you use wp_insert_user then it required valid email id. If you provide invalid email id then all field are updated but email not updated.

Answer (score -2):

```
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'gowp_remove_new_user_email_error', 10, 3 );
function gowp_remove_new_user_email_error( $errors, $update, $user ) {
        unset( $errors->errors['empty_email'] );
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?